# How to properly use instagram graph api catalog search?

Tags: facebook, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to search products by name. In the [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/catalog_product_search), it says that the product name or sku value can be specified in a parameter named q in the request:

[image: _]

I am looking for products whose name is equal to **fimo necklace**. This returns several results. here is my example request:

```
endpointParams = dict()
endpointParams['access_token'] = params['access_token']
endpointParams['q'] = 'fimo necklace'
url='https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/{instagram_account_id}/catalog_product_search?catalog_id=12345'
data=requests.get(url,endpointParams)
```

But the product i want is not among them. The first thing that caught my attention was that not all of the results matched exactly to the word I was looking for. Some kind of "like" query might be running. here are some returning values:

`['blue fimo necklace','sunset fimo necklace','blue nature fimo necklace']`

I got all the results using pagination but the product I was looking for was still not among them. There was no value **equal** to **fimo necklace** in them.
I want an output like this as a result:

`['fimo necklace']`

Comment: Hi could you find the solution to this?

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately no. On my side i am temporarily using a solution like this:
I search for the product name in my own database and search for each matching product with the api. If their prices match, it's okay.